# Можно ли загрузить другое(внешнее) приложение в свое?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Есть девайс с Andorid 6. Я написал небольшое приложение, из этого приложения поставил линки на запуск других (уже установленных) приложений. Это я сделал, всё работает.

Теперь вопрос вот в чем — можно ли сделать так, чтоб в моем приложении было что-то вроде фрейма, в который я мог бы загружать эти внешние приложения? Что бы мое приложение не сворачиволось, и в нем отображалось по середине в "окне", в заданных мною размерах (например 90% ширины, 80% высоты). Если возможно, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю можно только запустить другие приложения из своего. Запустить приложение в каком-либо `View` внутри своего приложения похоже невозможно.
Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869037/app-inside-an-app), может это натолкнет вас на что-то.

Comment: ок, я подозревал, что такое невозможно, но решил получить подтверждение.

Comment: Отметьте как решение тогда, мне это очень поможет :)